# How to remove divider of tab view and fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am working on an android project i am using tab view and i want to remove divider of tabs and fragment. what can i do?
this is the pic of my layout.
[image]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TabWidget
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:showDividers="none"
        style="@style/AppTheme" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using toolbar? if yes then add this property to toolbar "android:elevation="0dp"

Comment: please check my xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
<TabWidget ... 
android:tabStripEnabled="false" >

 ... 

</TabWidget>
```

Comment: @Masum: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue to make answer more helpful

Answer (score 1):

try using tablayout,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_30"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size_30"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_color"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabText"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It Will Help you

```
<TabWidget
android:tabStripEnabled="false"/ >
```

Please do this

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue